# How to convert Haryāna to Haryana with Ruby

Tags: ruby, encoding, utf-8, ascii

I am getting this value from an api and somehow it is sending some special unicode chars in the value. I would like to convert this into a normal ascii string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [`unidecoder`](https://rubygems.org/gems/unidecoder) gem:

```
require 'unidecoder'
"Haryāna".to_ascii # => "Haryana"
```